# github через ssh

Tags: github

Есть два аккаунта на github: vasya и petya, для каждого созданы ssh-ключи.
Удаленный репозиторий добавлен, указывая ссылку SSH из репозитория github.
При попытке пушить в удаленный репозиторий аккаунта petya, возникает ошибка, что на него нет прав у аккаунта vasya. ERROR: Permission to petya/progect.git denied to vasya.
Вопрос: почему происходит попытка от лица vasya?

Comment: А вы от какого лица пытаетесь пушить?

Comment: ключи у разных локальных пользователей? если нет, то как вы их указываете при общении с сайтом?

Comment: возможно проблема в настройках групп доступа к схову git (а именно в правах linux/unix), петя добавлен ли в группу, которой разрешён доступ к git?